# Git определяет файлы как измененные, но при этом файлы не менялись

Tags: git, git-status

Сначала я скачал основу и сделал первый коммит, потом скачал исходные файлы от другого пользователя и заменил те, что были в рабочей директории, но когда я ввожу `git status`, то git показывает примерно 10 из 40 файлов с подпиской modified, и из них только 3 были модифицированы, а все остальные нет, и WinMerge не находит каких-либо изменений, или `git add -i` пишет +0/-0 напротив этих файлов. Разницу между ними не нашел никакой, ни в размере, ни в содержании, ни в кодировке. Странно, что git пишет +0/-0, но при этом в `git status` помечает их как modified. На всякий случай вот пример с двумя файлами: 1. [link text](http://rghost.ru/6RJ4WTLGG). 2. [link text](http://rghost.ru/7HRGZxNww).

Comment: так как md5 и sha1 этих файлов совпадает, то с очень большой вероятностью, эти два файла идентичны.

а дата создания/модификации у этих файлов не поменялась случайно?

Можно попробовать для этих файлов сделать `git checkout -- имя_файла`.  И опять посмотреть результат. 

*Внимание, эта команда откатит содержимое файла до состояния предыдущего коммита!!!* Поэтому, применяйте только к тем файлам, которые Вы считаете не измененными.

Comment: Проблема может быть с правами доступа на файлы. Винда бывает их меняет на какие-то свои, так что после комита и последующего пула на стороне линухи, права оказываются далеко не такими, как были прежде.

Comment: Либо права сменили, либо перенос строк изменен.

Comment: @dimka3210

А оно повлияет?

Comment: @KoVadim, @dimka3210, @deterok, проблема в переносе строк оказалась, хотя я этот вариант проверял раньше, но может что-то напутал. Сейчас взял программу Windows-Unix Text Convertor и перевел все файлы в Unix, а потом в .gitconfig поставил `autocrlf = false`. Так вот, какие теперь это может принести проблемы? Учитывая, что программа разрабатывается и на linux и на windows, а также работает на обоих системах. То есть, с исходниками ещё кое-как, но с текстовыми файлами настроек и прочего, уже будут проблемы при считывании? Это решать в коде или в git все же ка-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня все нормально (Gentoo-x64, git-2.3.1).

Ищите косяки в форматирование файлов, может, ось чего пишет лишнего или чудо-WinMerge.

Покажите git diff.